# Meteor.call not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I had this code working before I wanted to change the client side collection find/insert methods to server side.  I removed insecure and autopublish from my meteor project, and changed my code to what it is below.

My angular Code in `client/controllers/item-controller.js`

```
    angular.module('prototype').controller('ItemController', ['Config','$window','$meteor', function(Config, $window, $meteor) {

    this.items = function(){
        Meteor.call('getAllItems', function(err, res){
            alert("error: " +err + " res: " + res );
            return res;
        });
    }
```

My item-collection codee in `server/item-collection-methods.js`

```
Meteor.methods({
    getAllItems : function(){
        console.log("i got here")
        return Items.find();
    }
});
```

My main file in `lib/app.js`

```
Items = new Mongo.Collection("Items");
```

Before I had 15 items showing, now none of them show.

when I copy my Meteor.call function into the chrome console, all I get back is `undefined`.

I have a feeling it either has to do with the project structure, or the fact that autopublish and insecure are removed.  Any advice would be helpful.

EDIT:

I did get something in my server console

```
I20150629-00:54:54.402(-4)? Internal exception while processing message { msg: '
method', method: 'getAllItems', params: [], id: '2' } Maximum call stack si
ze exceeded undefined
```

Comment: Well... since you removed autopublish, you're manually publishing on the server and subscribing to the data in Iron Router or on your templates, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor data transmission works with a publish/subscribe system. This system is able to replicate part of or all the data that is stored in your MongoDB (server) to the client in an in-memory DB (MiniMongo). Autopublish was publishing everything on the client, as you removed it there is nothing in your `Items` collection anymore.

In order to publish some data to the client you have to declare a publication on the server side:

```
Meteor.publish('allItems', function () { 
  //collection to publish
  return Items.find({});
});
```

And subscribe on the client (either in the router or in a template):

```
Meteor.subscribe('allItems');
```

To learn more about this system you can read the [official docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish).

Concerning your method "getAllItems", you cannot directly send a cursor (`Items.find()`) on your data, that is why you are getting the error message "Maximum call stack size exceeded".
But you could send an array of these data by returning `Items.find().fetch()`. Also the call to a Meteor method is asynchronous, so you have to use the callback ([more on Meteor methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods))
Please note that by sending data over a method (which is perfectly acceptable) you lose the reactivity offered by the publish/subscribe system.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, all my "reads" should be pub/sub based so I get the reactivate behavior from updates.  My writes (since that's really what I'm trying to protect, just trying to get a read to work for simplicity) should be methods so I can sanitize the inputs.

Comment: Right :) Note that you can secure both methods and publish functions for example by checking if the user is logged in if she has the necessary role (admin...) etc.